# Optimize huge query to be eager loaded

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a huge query that needs to be modified right now it doesn't eager load the withCount, whenever I call `propertyimages_count` it always return 0 instead of the correct count. But if I call `$property->propertyimages()->count()` it returns the correct number but it is not eager loading.

I'm not really sure why propertyimages_count, I am thinking maybe it is the alias.

```
$search = (isset($_GET['sSearch']) ? $_GET['sSearch'] : ''); 

    $get = $this->method_vars($_GET);

    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    $where =  Property::
      withCount('propertyimages')
    ->with(['project', 'latestmaintenance', 'propertyimages'])
    ->join('projects', 'properties.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
    ->where(function( $query ) use ($get) {

        if($get['price_from'] >= 1 && $get['price_to'] <= 500000) {
            $query->whereBetween('rental_price', [$get['price_from'], $get['price_to'] ]);
        }

        $query = $get['sqm_from'] >= 1 && $get['sqm_to'] <= 1000 ? $query->whereBetween('sqm', [$get['sqm_from'], $get['sqm_to'] ]) : $query;


        if( $get['type'] != '' ) {
            if( $get['type'] == 'house' ) {
                $query->where('projects.type', 'Housing Project');
            } else if( $get['type'] == 'condo' ) {
                $query->where('projects.type', 'Condo Project');
            } else if( $get['type'] == 'any' ) {
                $query->whereIn('projects.type', ['Condo Project', 'Housing Project']);
            }
        }

        $query = $get['view'] != '' ? $query->where('view', $get['view']) : $query;
        $query = $get['project'] != '' ? $query->where('project_id', $get['project']) : $query;
        $query = $get['bedrooms'] != '' ? $query->where('bedrooms', $get['bedrooms']) : $query;
        $query = $get['bathrooms'] != '' ? $query->where('bathrooms', $get['bathrooms']) : $query;
        $query = $get['property_status'] != '' ? $query->where('status', $get['property_status']) : $query;

        if( $get['status'] != '' ) {
            if( $get['status'] == 'rented' ) {
                $query->whereRaw('CURDATE() >= check_in')->whereRaw('CURDATE() <= check_out');
            } elseif( $get['status'] == 'vacant' ) {
                $query->where(function($q) {
                    $q->whereRaw('CURDATE() NOT BETWEEN check_in AND check_out')->orWhereNull('check_in');
                });
            }
        }
    })
    ->orderBy('projects.name')
    ->orderBy('unit')
    ->whereRaw("(SELECT check_in 
        FROM property_rentals 
        WHERE property_rentals.property_id = properties.id 
        ORDER BY 
        CASE 
        WHEN check_out >= '{$today}' AND check_in <= '{$today}' THEN 0  
        WHEN check_in > '{$today}' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
        END
        LIMIT 1) as check_in")
    ->whereRaw("(SELECT check_out 
        FROM property_rentals 
        WHERE property_rentals.property_id = properties.id 
        ORDER BY 
        CASE 
        WHEN check_out >= '{$today}' AND check_in <= '{$today}' THEN 0  
        WHEN check_in > '{$today}' THEN 1
        ELSE 2
        END
        LIMIT 1) as check_out");
```

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 is this?

Comment: @RossWilson version 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to add count images relation, something like this:

```
public function imagesCount()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ProperyImage')
    ->selectRaw('property_id, count(*) as count)
    ->groupBy('property_id');
}
```

...and then add it to the with clause

[Check this](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-hasmany-relation-count-efficiently/)